# Why is my regex returning false?

Tags: php, regex

Ok so Im selecting some scraped text from my db and trying to parse for the phone number. Its in there and Im not getting any errors but the `var_dump` is returning `int 0` Why? Here's the code

```
$query1 = "SELECT adtext, `key`  FROM usedcars WHERE `key` = $x";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

    $link_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link_result);



    //now parse that number

     $phone_number = preg_match("/^((([0-9]{1})*[- .(]*([0-9]{3})[- .)]*[0-9]{3}[- .]*[0-9]{4})+)*$/", $result['adtext']);

     var_dump($phone_number);
    }
```

Btw, this is a part of a loop that iterates through each rowin the db. Like I said, its not throwing an error, just not recognizing the number so I think maybe there is something wrong with the regex or idk. Here is the particular text its `preg_match`-ing

```
    2001 Ford POS in great condition but definitely Im a liar and it will break down before you get home. Fix.Or.Repair.Daily that what I always say<br>
<br>
NO Blocked Calls<br>
<br>
I AM IN WASHINGTON D.C / VIRGINIA / MARYLAND Local buyers only<br>
<br>
<b>No warranty</b><br>Forsale by owner<br>
<br>
<b>Accepting first offer</b>
<b>24 hours call  <u><b>Call Me â˜Ž 202-510-5939</b></b></u>


   </div>


     <p class="metaInfoDisplay">Poster's Reputation: 0<br></p>





     <div style="padding-left:2em;">
       &bull; Location: 

         Northern Virginia, â˜Ž 202-210-5936

     </div>




     <div style="padding-left:2em;"><br />&bull; Post ID: 1234567 washingtondc</div>


       <div id="OtherAdsByThisUser" data-oid="7654321">
```

Help a slow guy out please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([0-9]?[- .(]*[0-9]{3}[- .)][0-9]{3}[- .][0-9]{4})
```

Didn't exactly understand your regex but you can try this.More testing would be required though.Try here.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/1

Your regex will not work because of the anchors `^` and `&`. They will match the start and end of the line. I have removed them and modified your regex.

Comment: @tommyg you can try http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/2 this as well if you want to keep your own regex.